# How to Create Custom Controls for IPhone?

Tags: iphone

Hii friends,

i m new to iphone development and i have gone through some iphone applications with awesome UI design.

i guess those UIElements are not standard Iphone controls,if so

- How to create Custom Controls or any different nice look for controls?

Thanks to all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [three20](http://three20.info/overview#UI) UI Library.